# Can't get a div element in the output

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm quite new at front-end development. I was just experimenting with HTML/CSS. After making a simple poster, I was trying to make simple freestyle(not specific to any kind of website) page layout.

Here is what I did.

https://github.com/imdpm/CodoSapiens/tree/master/LayAtt

I'm trying to add a "content" type division. I've created a style for it in style.css and invoked it in index.html without any content. Just the division.

But output does not have any "content" division. I can't seem to understand where I have made a mistake.

Could anyone help?

```css
body{
  background-image: url("BackIm.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#icon{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
}
.topmenu{
  background-color: #001a00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.sidemenu{
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: black;
  position: left fixed relative;
  margin: 190px 80px 0 40px;
  padding: 8px 6px 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  max-width: 155px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.banner{
  background-color: #FFA500;
  position: absolute;
  top:44px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 125px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #228B22;
}
.content{
  background-color: #5651F3;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  right: 30px;
  left: 25px;
}
#link{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2px 0 1px 0;
  color:grey;
  font-size:35px;
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
  font-weight:bold
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
}
hr{
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LayoutAtt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="topmenu">
      <img id="icon" src="https://github.com/imdpm/CodoSapiens/blob/master/LayAtt/BackIm.jpg?raw=true" alt="Icon">
      <a id="link" href="index.html">BackToBeg</a>
    </div>

    <div class="banner">
    </div>

    <div class="sidemenu">
      <a href="index.html">BackToBeg</a><hr>
      <a href="index.html">BackToBeg</a><hr>
      <a href="index.html">BackToBeg</a><hr>
      <a href="index.html">BackToBeg</a><hr>
      <a href="index.html">BackToBeg</a><hr>
    </div>

    <div class="content">      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a width and a height to your content div. 
Try this

```
.content{
  background-color: #5651F3;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  right: 30px;
  left: 25px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Use the inspector in the browser to look at the html and css being rendered. You can see what styles are being applied to which elements.

Comment: Mark this as the answer if it works for you. Cheers and happy coding.

Comment: Thanks. Division is showing now, but not where I want it to be - to the right of "sidemenu".

Comment: You can use a  `float:right` on your content class to make the div float to the right of the menu. Please mark this as the answer as it answers your original question. Cheers